# Mongoose does mot properly handle date string in aggregation unless I hardcode it

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDb orders collection that has a field called order_date which indicates the year a customer made a purchase. I want to be able to query for a customer's orders up to 5 years ago. The collection fields look like below

```
     
    customer_id: '12345',
    transaction_id: 'TXN-0999999',
    order_date: '2022-09-13T13:30:00.000+00:00'
    shipping_street: 'Pike Street',
    shipping_house_num: '1121',
    shipping_city: 'Albany',
    shipping_state: 'New York',
    ...
```

If I hard code the date string for an order_date range, it works as below, however since the dates are dynamic I use a function to get the dates as strings. When I use them in the aggregation pipeline it does not work.   This is an example of an hardcoded date
{order_date:{$gte:new Date("2020-10-19T20:26:27.264Z"),$lt: new Date("2018-10-19T20:31:19.708Z")}}

This is part of what mongoose generates when I log the query

Mongoose: productModel.aggregate([ { '$match': { order_date: { '$gte': 2022-10-25T01:23:57.166Z, '$lte': 2023-10-25T01:23:57.167Z } } } ], {})

I notice that the dates don't look right.

I generate the date like new Date('datestr).toISOString() and use that in the $match which does not work.  How can I pass a dynamic date to Mongoose to work?

Comment: 1. Are you storing date as Date type but not string in the collection? 2. Your date range criteria is 1 millisecond (166 - 167) difference, have you confirm that any document are within this range?

Comment: I am using date as  { $match: { order_date: : { $gte: new Date(...) i etc. n the queries.  Like I said, if I take the generated dates hard code and run the queries as a pipeline it returns the results, so there is nothing wrong with the query besides how mongoose is handiling the dates. The date strings are from  mongoose.set(log, debug)  which is converting my new Date() to a string it seems. I am not using a string but new Date(date_string)